# how to avoid python numeric literals beginning with "0" being treated as octal?

Tags: python, octal, pep

I am trying to write a small Python 2.x API to support fetching a
`job` by `jobNumber`, where `jobNumber` is provided as an integer.
Sometimes the users provide a`jobNumber` as an integer literal
beginning with 0, e.g. `037537`.  (This is because they have been
coddled by R, a language that sanely considers `037537==37537`.)
Python, however, considers integer literals starting with "0" to
be OCTAL, thus `037537!=37537`, instead `037537==16223`.  This
strikes me as a blatant affront to the principle of least
surprise, and thankfully it looks like this was fixed in Python
3---see [PEP 3127](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127).

But I'm stuck with Python 2.7 at the moment.  So my users do this:

```
>>> fetchJob(037537)
```

and silently get the wrong job (16223), or this:

```
>>> fetchJob(038537)
File "<stdin>", line 1
 fetchJob(038537)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

where Python is rejecting the octal-incompatible digit.

There doesn't seem to be anything provided via `__future__` to
allow me to get the Py3K behavior---it would have to be built-in
to Python in some manner, since it requires a change to the lexer
at least.

Is anyone aware of how I could protect my users from getting the
wrong job in cases like this?  At the moment the best I can think
of is to change that API so it take a string instead of an int.

Comment: Don't be so sure it's fixed in Python 3. From the PEP: "an exception will be raised if a literal has a leading "0" and a second character which is a digit." So instead of getting a surprising number, you'll get a surprising exception. I don't see how that's an improvement.

Comment: 1) Train the users? 2) Force a string or (and not sure about this), are all job numbers 6 digits?

Comment: @MarkRansom-- surely you jest.  A surprising exception is very much an improvement over silently doing something very surprising.

Comment: Looking at the source (Python 2.7.3), it looks like a small change to `Parser/tokenizer.c` should fix this issue. I guess it all depends on how "under the hood you want to get" :)

Comment: @DSM, OK perhaps an in-your-face surprise is better than a silent surprise. "Hey doctor, it hurts when I do this" - "Well next time you do it we'll amputate your arm".

Comment: "Hey Python, it hurts when I do this" - "Well next time you should read the docs instead of assuming". If you truly care about type safety, use a type-secure language, otherwise stay within defined bounds of an unsafe language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> At the moment the best I can think of is to change that API so it take a string instead of an int.

Yes, and I think this is a reasonable option given the situation.

Another option would be to make sure that all your job numbers contain at least one digit greater than 7 so that adding the leading zero will give an error immediately instead of an incorrect result, but that seems like a bigger hack than using strings.

A final option could be to educate your users. It will only take five minutes or so to explain not to add the leading zero and what can happen if you do. Even if they forget or accidentally add the zero due to old habits, they are more likely to spot the problem if they have heard of it before.

Comment: You could also display the `int` value in the stdout. Kind of along the lines of educating the user.

Comment: I think this is what I'm going with for now.  Thanks for all the suggestions.  Can't change the Python source code---I was hoping there was a `__future__` built-in that would do this for me.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could take the input as a string, strip leading zeros, then convert back to an int?

```
test = "001234505"
test = int(test.lstrip("0"))  # 1234505
```

Comment: This doesn't support literals that are sign-prefixed, i.e. `+0012345`